# Looping "Batch Export" Crashes - Processor or Code Error?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, batch-processing

Why can't Excel loop through large datasets?!

I have 2 different document forms which need to be exported to PDF by the hundreds. I pulled the batch export script from the internet and modified it for my usage so it would process either of these forms depending on the checkbox selected on the "Batch PDF Printer" worksheet.

Everything runs well - for the first 10-15 workbooks accessed by the loop, and then it crashes. Every Excel document freezes (Not Responding) and the page that is currently accessed by the Macro partially opens with no visible data or cells. The "Publishing" message box may also freeze at this point. Once it reported a lack of memory error - but I have not been able to repeat this.  Shouldn't Excel be deleting unused cache's so as to not overload the memory? I would suspect a bum loop if it didn't run well for a while. I've heard there is no way to script in a "cache dump" or something of that nature. Is it bad code, or am I asking too much of my processor?

```
Sub Convert2PDF()
'Update the checkbox linked formulas on the GUI workbook
Sheet1.Range("A2").Formula = Sheet1.Range("A2").Formula
Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula = Sheet1.Range("B2").Formula
Sheet1.Range("C2").Formula = Sheet1.Range("C2").Formula

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strXLFile As String
Dim strPDFFile As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim lngPos As Long
' set folder
strFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\putfileshere" & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Get first filename
strXLFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
' Loop through Excel workbooks in folder
Do While strXLFile <> ""
    ' Open workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strXLFile)
    ' Assemble the PDF filename
    lngPos = InStrRev(strXLFile, ".")
    strPDFFile = Left(strXLFile, lngPos) & "pdf"
    ' Export to PDF
    'Do the next 8 lines crash the Macro because they recalculate for every sheet? Page1, Page2, Page3 value are the same for all workbooks processed in a batch
            Dim Page1 As String
            Dim Page2 As String
            Dim Page3 As String
            Dim Page4 As String
                Page1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch PDF Printer").Range("A2")
                Page2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch PDF Printer").Range("B2")
                Page3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch PDF Printer").Range("C2")

            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch PDF Printer").Range("C2") = "" Then 
                wbk.Sheets(Array(Page1, Page2)).Select
                ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdfsgohere" & "\" & wbk.Name, _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

'run process for format option 2
            Else:
                wbk.Sheets(Array(Page1, Page2, Page3)).Select
                ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdfsgohere" & "\" & wbk.Name, _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            'Tried killing the finished document to improve function
                Dim xFullName As String
                xFullName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
                Application.ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
                Kill xFullName
                Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

            End If
    ' Close workbook - didn't seem to help (can't do it when the workbook is gone)
       'wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Get next filename
    strXLFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "All Done"
```

Thanks for the help. I've been trying to figure this out for days now.

Comment: "and then it crashes" - how exactly does it crash?

Comment: I updated my post to clarify this. Thank you.

Comment: That's not necessarily a crash - it sounds like it's just **busy**.  What if you put a `Stop` or even just `DoEvents` within the loop?

Comment: Also helpful would be a `Debug.Print "something"` line in the loop so you can see how it's progressing in the Immediate Window (CTRL+G).  [Here is more on that](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) and other debugging tips from the amazing Chip Pearson.

Comment: Wouldn't ceding to the processor in that manner help if the CPU or RAM had been overloaded? My PC isn't reporting any functional usage over 50% and nothing else is slow while executing the code. It's only effecting Excel documents (even those unrelated to the code). I will try a DoEvents to see if it helps.

Comment: DoEvents improves function to the point it will always run through exactly 14 iterations before freezing and closing down all Excel processes and windows. It's something.

Comment: This symptom has already been reported in many posts in this forum. The reason may be the difference between the speed of the memory and the disk. (Roughly: mem: 100 GB/s, SSD: 3 GB/s, HDD: 100 MB/s. ) So what actually happens is that disk cashes the first 10-15 files at memory speed and then everything slows down to disk speed until the disk can empty the cache. So what I would do is to test it with 20 and then 50 files to see if it works at all, and comment out screenupdating and insert `Application.DisplayStatusBar = xFullName`. It will be slower but you will see the progress.

Comment: AcsErno, I am already tracking progress in the folder "ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdfsgohere"". That's how I know it is executing exactly 14 iterations before crashing. I have not found the appropriate solution listed in this forum. If you are aware that this has been discussed, some links or keywords to those questions would be helpful. Should I be programming in a run-time pause, or do I need to completely restart excel and have the code re-initiate the runtime from the fault point?

Comment: Is it always the same file when it fails?  If Yes, have you tried removing that file?

Comment: BTW you're saving your PDF files as `wbk.Name` and not as `strPDFFile`

Comment: Thanks for the note, Tim. The strPDFFile is a relic from the slug code which I need to remove.  I have been trying with batches of 20 - completely different files each time. At first I thought something in one of the workbooks may have been the issue, but that does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This ran for me on >30 files with no problem:

```
Sub Convert2PDF()

    Dim strFolder As String, strXLFile As String
    Dim strPDFFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim lngPos As Long
    Dim pages(1 To 4) As String
    Dim shtBatch As Worksheet, arr

    Set shtBatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Batch PDF Printer")
    shtBatch.Range("A2:C2").Calculate '<< assume this was the point of resetting the formulas?
    pages(1) = shtBatch.Range("A2").Value
    pages(2) = shtBatch.Range("B2").Value
    pages(3) = shtBatch.Range("C2").Value

    'what pages to print?  Only need to do this once
    arr = IIf(Len(pages(3)) = 0, Array(pages(1), pages(2)), _
                                 Array(pages(1), pages(2), pages(3)))

    strFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\putfileshere\"
    strXLFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")

    Do While strXLFile <> ""

        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strXLFile, ReadOnly:=True)

        lngPos = InStrRev(strXLFile, ".")
        strPDFFile = Left(strXLFile, lngPos) & "pdf"

        wbk.Sheets(arr).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdfsgohere\" & strPDFFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        wbk.Close False

        strXLFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "All Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, you're amazing for trying to make this work and adapting variables to my specific project. Also, thank you for introducing me to IIF. I bumbled my way through that operation because I didn't know it existed. Unfortunately, your streamlined code is producing nearly identical results. 14 PDFs produced - then the main workbook crashes and auto-restarts. However, your code does not crash the entire Excel application and all open workbooks. This is an improvement. Thank you so much for taking the time to bother with this. I'm going to experiment more with feeding it different/new workbooks.

Comment: The second run produced 13 PDFs before freezing the entire application. Before killing it and trying again, I watched my processor usage skyrocket. I was using about 40-50% of my 3.63 GHz during run time, but AFTER it froze up the computer really started trying to crunch something. There are quite a few formulas and VBA computations in the sheets being exported. Could this be the cause, and how should those be disabled when the macro opens a book to export?

Comment: My sample workbooks we’re quite simple, so it’s possible your cpu load is mainly due to opening multiple “heavy” workbooks in wick succession.  What happens if you comment out the export to pdf step?  Does it still fail?

Comment: I left the wbk.Sheets(arr).Select and commented all of the export parameters. Works like a charm. So maybe it's not a VBA issue, but an Adobe issue?

Comment: Updated Adobe. No change.

Comment: If you introduce a short wait after each export that might help.  It might slow down the process but one of the big points about automation is you can be doing other things while it runs.

Comment: I looked into "waits" but was not able to wrap my head around the tutorials I found. I'm a biologist happy to have learned as much coding as I have. Thank you for the help, Tim. Getting this to function is really a major asset to my weekly workload. You taught me some really useful new functions and lined me up to think more critically about the processing going on with the code.

Comment: You can do simple waits with Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(h,m,s) where h is hours, m is minutes, s is seconds https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timeserial-function

Comment: Points to QHarr. Thanks.

Comment: FYI the “native” Office save as PDF doesn’t use Adobe to run the export

Answer (score 0):

Even if your visible system RAM is not overloading, the internal capacity of the Excel application seems to be exceeded for a brief moment. I was able to finally view the message box "Not enough system resources to display completely" before the app went into automatic reboot. Try streamlining the workbooks being accessed by the loop. If your workbooks take a while to start up, that may be indication of heavy background processes (calculations and VBA subs). DoEvents may help the code run more smoothly by asking for more processing time so the system can sort it's demands. Ultimately,

Application.Calculation = xlManual

at the top of the loop was sufficient to reduce the computational demands on the 20 gig system (which I never expected to overload).

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked images in your exports.

Exported linked images leaves behind a bit or byte in the kernel, which accumulates and eventually breaks excel.

I found this solution only 1 place on the internet and i cannot find it again, but it got me from 200s to 1000 loops of VBA Macro by removing linked images.

Nothing in the VBA code would help, i used pauses, save the workbook to clear memory, disable events etc...

I wrote an answer to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600884/10069870

Disregard if you have no linked images in your exports :)