# VBA loop crashes after 40 or 60 loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-while

i've been googling my eyes out and i'm very much a novice.

I'm using a macro to run through a list of customer id, filter a pivot with the id, export a sheet as pdf then repeat the loop.

I have finally after several days managed to get it to run for 60 times but about then it restarts excel. I have just increased the pagefile from 2gb to 16gb.

I'm using a do while loop and im trying to set objects = nothing to clean up resources and im saving the file at one point and i also am using DoEvents, set screenupdate to false, set microsoft xps as default printer, print comms to false, all ranges are stores in variables instead of selected, worksheets are also stored in variables instead of being activated. I have tried stepping through, using breakpoints etc... and seeing as it runs 60 times without errors..

My guess is that since it's upped from 40 to 60 before crash that it might have to do with resources being bloated over time.

Removed code as i found out the crashing had nothing to do with the VBA code, but linked images.

Comment: Try to see if any of the following helps: you can help the question by trying to see how to minimise the code to *reproduce this issue*. My guess (from my 2002 experience) is that adding many new objects could cause a crash. And back then I've done exactly what you've suggested.

Comment: @HilaDG i'm sorry i'm not sure what you are suggesting? :)

Comment: i have been thinking, would it be smarter to put the "exportas PDF" into a separate module and call it. my reasoning being that when the sub ends in that module the resources should be cleared?

Comment: Why are you using `DoEvents`?

Comment: @MichaelChristensen: the issue you have is that Excel is crashing. My idea is to try and locate what's the minimum amount of code required to reproduce this issue. Is it the email creation or is it the PDF creation? Also, it could be that this problem does not have a solution. I hope you'll find one!

Comment: @catcat i have had several different types of crashes/freezes etc.. i included it in the hopes that it eliminates somes and also it should make it easier to break the code if i need to?

Comment: i can see that the memory used is slowly creeping when the macro is running, lowest amount starts around 245mb when the file is opening, 400mb when the macro starts running.. and about 685mb when it crashes.. it goes into the 800mb at some stages without crashing..

Comment: as far as i can tell... i need to isolate which part of my loop is slowly bloating the memory :(   i tried to set pivottable manual update = true.. but that results in a pdf with "reference#" all over the place so i need the update to happen.

Comment: @HilaDG the email creation is commented out for now, that was my first suspect. So it's not that.. im thinking either its the filtering of pivottable or exportaspdf that is slowly bloating the memory

Comment: It the most likely cause of crashes. Post your entire code.

Comment: If you think one thing (such as save to pdf) is causing a problem, then comment it out and run again, and see what changes.

Comment: I have commented out the doevents.. I am now trying to run filterpivot separately and exporttopdf separately while watching the memory..

Comment: so... both filter pivot and exportpdf bloats the memory over time when run separately

Comment: Try swapping out your `'empty the clipboard` code with the following: `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: @DirtyDeffy i have actually commented it out completely and no change

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but i don't understand what range you're trying to target with this type of line: `Worksheets("error").Range("temp").Value = temp` you set `temp` to a string, but then use it in a range. Could you explain what your thoughts are with this? :)

Comment: That is not your entire code. There is no `Sub...End Sub` so we can't tell if it's all of it.

Comment: @catcat i know.. i'm just testing like a madman and making lil changes here n there.. also two different versions. I'll poste a copy soon.

Comment: i was wondering.. would it help if the macro shuts down after X loops and then restarts the macro as if it was a new macrosession.. would that drop the memory used? i just dont quite know how to go about that. I have a counter that lets the macro pick up where it broke so i can open the file if it shutsdown, hit the button and do another batch. I just dont wanna do that 21 times over a period of 6 hours

Comment: Is Excel 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: i testing it on both 32 n 64. Currently the 32bit stays around 400-500MB through the run.. but will at some point just hang or restart. 64bit will go into the 600-800MB memory range and at some point restart. Im using microsoft pdf printer as default printer on the 32bit. I have just tried a "if N mod 60 then restart" hoping that it will reset the memory. sorry for not posting entire code yet.. im just trying all sorts of things as this was supposed to have been up n running last week.. people are waiting on me :(  i had only tested 15 - 24 runs and no hiccups..

Comment: my code is too long for comments.. should i update op ? Post updated with full module.. there are 2 modules being called besides this, export to pdf and filter pivot.. exportpdf: Application.PrintCommunication = False

printrng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filnavn

Application.PrintCommunication = True

Comment: maybe it is nothing with memory.. but powerpivot crashing upon the pivot filtering, i tried an "update" by right clicking the pivot and mashup bloated into 1.xgb memory and got stuck there... i have tried to disable the backstage caching of powerpivot data

Comment: testing the macro in safemode now

Comment: safemode also restarted excel... now i've removed all vba modules, saved as xls closed file, disabled hardware accelerated graphics, ignorering other applications dde, removed edit data for images. Opened the xls file imported all modules and saved as macrofile again and restarted macro..

Comment: i might have solved it... still unsure and testing.. but i have 4 images that can change depending on an indexmatch lookup for a eye catching background on certain values. I removed these images and am running without background on two machines... knock on wood... it looks like it's chugging comfortably along with as much as 80 files without crashing..

Comment: even if this solves it.. i'd be happy to recieve pointers on the code so i can get better at making more smooth and performance agile code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removing linked images** in the worksheet that is exported fixed my issue.

I am not sure i fully understood the solution i found, but in rough terms:
Apparently the export feature leaves behind a bit or byte in the kernel of the linked image and this accumulates on each pass of the macro, eventually breaking things down.

Unfortunately i only found 1 other similar problem back when i was googling like a mad man, so i cannot link to where i found this information.

I would like to thank all commenters for their time and help back then, i got it all working and it now produces 900-1000 individual PDFs and attached them an email and sends it off.

So in **conclusion**:
If you are exporting a worksheet to pdf with VBA macro, that includes linked images they can cause instability and eventually crash your macro.
**Try** to not link images.

**If you need images:**
I used linked images because i needed them to be dynamic and change according to requirements. I found another way to do this, that inserts appropiate image instead (with a delete function first in case a previous inserted image exists). I did not write that code myself if i remember correctly, but it involves:

- Having my images in a folder.
- Naming each image to match a value in excel.
- Creating a variable in vba that is: imgfile = path & value &
  ".png".
- Then i SET IMG = ws.pictures.insert(imgfile) I then insert
  this as an img object.

  ```
   With img
          .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
          .Left = ws.Range("g15").Left
          .Top = ws.Range("g15").Top
          .Width = R.Width
          .Height = R.Height
          .Placement = 1
          .PrintObject = True
           nameofpicture = .Name
   End With
  ```

before i use this i call a deletepicture sub, be mindful of only deleting the image(s) you need to change.

```
Sub deletepictures()

Dim pic As Shape
Dim radd As String
radd = Range("g14").Address

For Each pic In Worksheets("Rapport").Shapes        
    If Left(pic.Name, 3) = "Pic" Then pic.Delete    
    Next pic
End Sub
```

I hope someone else will find this useful, it's a tricky thing to google took me about two full weeks worktime to find useful information about.